# Android Launcher Icon Including Text

Tags: android, icons

I have often heard that it is bad form to include text within a launcher icon. Can can anyone provide proof for this? Apple has it in their guidelines but I can not find anything in the Google specs.

Thanks

Comment: It's considered counterproductive since the text is already present in the Label of the icon. Also, if your text is long, you could not benefit from it since the icons won't be as large to make it look comfortably spaced. Apart from that, your icon would look far too congested and not pretty to look at.

Comment: I agree, but do you know of Google ever added this as a thing to avoid?

Comment: There isn't anything explicitly mentioned in the guidelines to not use text in icons. You could obviously stylish text in Material Design with say 1-3 letters at max and then add it. As long as it doesn't feel congested, I feel it's great to go.

Comment: It would help us answer the question if you explained why you think the text might be needed. Are you talking about static text as a part of the icon or some kind of label on the icon indicating status within the app?

Answer (score 1):

Apple is enforcing common standards around icon look & feel while trying to enforce consistent and clean UI for their devices.

I agree with [@Swapnil Borkar](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/68872/swapnil-borkar) and others, it is redundant to have an icon hold an app name because the app name is already present right below the icon.

#### More broad Question

*Is it a bad practice to include text into an icon?*

**No**, as long as the text / copy is legible and does not duplicate any copy around it.